# Scraping multiple pages with Python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape many pages in Python using BeautifulSoup but with no positive results.

I tried using `request.get()` and `session.get()`. The number of pages I should scrape is 92.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
with requests.Session as session:
    count = 0
    for i in range(92):
        count+=1
        page = "https://www.paginegialle.it/lazio/roma/dentisti/p-"+str(count)+".html"
        r = session.get(page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Using `print(page)` the page are formatted corectly. But executing `soup` to print all the values stored in the variable, only the values of the first page are printed.
I'm using a jupyter notebook

Comment: What do you mean by "executing ```soup``` to print all the values"? What is the code you are using to print those values? At the moment your code simply overwrites what's in the ```soup``` variable each time around in the loop.

Comment: I mean i simply write soup and execute it (Shift+Enter).

Comment: Where/when do you do that? You have a loop there, after all.

Comment: in a new cell, after having executed the present code

Comment: Then you should always have the _last_ page's content in ```soup```. I think your code is basically correct but you should do some processing of ```soup``` _in_ the loop.

Comment: I'll try to figure it out. I was looking on stackoverflow but the solution provided does not work for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207060/discussion-between-okenite-and-myke).

Answer (score 1):

you can do as below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

for i in range(92):
    url = "https://www.paginegialle.it/lazio/roma/dentisti/p-"+str(i)+".html"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    p = soup.select('p')
    print(len(p))
```

[image]

Comment: @Okenite - retry the above

Comment: I re-editated my code because basically it was correct, but i added in the same cell and in the `for` loop the rest of the code. The `p = soup.select('p')` wasn't useful for what I needed. By the way I retrived only 177 results out of 2000, so I think there is something else I'm not considering right now, maybe a timeout in the request. I'll further analyze the problem .

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

count = 0
for i in range(92):
   count +=1
   source1 = requests.get("https://www.paginegialle.it/lazio/roma/dentisti/p-"+str(count)+".html").text 

   soup1 = BeautifulSoup(source1, 'lxml')

   print(soup1.body)
   print()
print("done")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

```
from simplified_scrapy.request import req
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc
count = 0
for i in range(92):
    count+=1
    html = req.get('https://www.paginegialle.it/lazio/roma/dentisti/p-'+str(i)+'.html') 
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
    print(doc.select('title>text()'))
print (count)
```